Display text at the end and right at each line in ggplot2 in R
i have a data frame in R called df_ that looks like this :
df_
# A tibble: 40 × 4
# Groups:   Year [5]
    Year Country    mu Color 
   <int> <fct>   <dbl> <fct> 
 1  2019 ALPHA    68.9 red   
 2  2019 BETA     64.8 black 
 3  2019 GAMMA    70.0 yellow
 4  2019 RHO      65.2 gray  
 5  2019 DELTA    70.1 green 
 6  2019 EPSILON  69.6 pink  
 7  2019 THETA    69.8 purple
 8  2019 OMEGA    67.9 orange
 9  2020 ALPHA    69.3 red   
10  2020 BETA     65.2 black 
# ℹ 30 more rows

i want 2 things:
a) to apply each line the color of the corresponding country
b) at the end of each line to display the text of each country column and the last value (ie the year 2024) . For example at the end and at the right of the line to display ("ALPHA ,76.4").
How can i do these in R using ggplot2 ?
ggplot(df_, aes(x = Year, y = mu,color = Color, group =Country)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Years", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")  


data
structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2024L, 
2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L), Country = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L), levels = c("ALPHA", "BETA", "DELTA", 
"EPSILON", "GAMMA", "OMEGA", "RHO", "THETA"), class = "factor"), 
    mu = c(68.855, 64.77, 69.9875, 65.22, 70.1266666666667, 69.6166666666667, 
    69.8085714285714, 67.9093333333333, 69.2675, 65.2, 72.4075, 
    69.49, 72.28, 69.262, 70.07125, 65.3864285714286, 74.6584615384615, 
    67.77, 75.3533333333333, 73, 64.09, 73.1715384615385, 66.058, 
    72.12, 75.5645833333333, 70.46, 78.2933333333333, 79.07, 
    59.82, 79.6361538461538, 74.225, 69.5871428571429, 76.4007407407407, 
    67.91, 76.805, 77.31, 74.0966666666667, 81.2811764705882, 
    74.6671428571428, 78.0316666666667), Color = structure(c(7L, 
    1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
    7L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
    4L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L), levels = c("black", 
    "gray", "green", "orange", "pink", "purple", "red", "yellow"
    ), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2019L, 2020L, 2022L, 2023L, 2024L), .rows = structure(list(
        1:8, 9:16, 17:24, 25:32, 33:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))


edit
addding:
  mutate(label = if_else(Year == max(Year), as.character(Country), NA_character_))

in the data frame and in the plot :
  theme(legend.position = "none")  +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = label),
                   nudge_x = 1,
                   na.rm = TRUE)


creates : 

There are plenty of answers on SO describing both parts. What have you tried?

@freddie no can you please show me? i would appreciate it

There are plenty of options.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
X |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=mu, colour=Color, group=Country), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=mu, colour=Color, group=Country)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = X |> filter(Year==2024) |> 
              mutate(lbl=sprintf("%s, %.01f", Country, mu)),
              aes(label=lbl, x=Year, y=mu, colour=Color), 
              nudge_x=.5, size=2.5) + 
  labs(x="Years", y="") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none") 

where X is your data. For example, a reference on SO can be found here.
